# Problem trying to install Logitech G Hub in Ubuntu in order to use it with headphones (wine, winetricks and PlayOnLinux didn't worked)

Tags: sound, wine, microphone, playonlinux, logitech

I've recently got a Logitech X Pro Headset (the wired version), the one that comes with Blue microphone.

In order to change the default settings I need to install [Logitech G Hub](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/innovation/g-hub.html) software, that comes for linux and Mac...

Of course everything works out of the box for the basics that I need, as I do use to teach online, but I really wanted to use the [extra features of the mic](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/innovation/blue-voice-technology.html). I've tried installing Wine, Winetricks and finally PlayOnLinux, but it does not allow me to install it.

I'm using **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS** and **wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)**, and when I do:
`wine lghub.exe` on the terminal, I get

> 002b:err:mscoree:CLRRuntimeInfo_GetRuntimeHost Wine Mono is not
> installed

When using PlayOnLinux, I get:

> Error in POL_Wine Wine seems to have crashed If your program is
> running, just ignore this message.

What should I do? I've read about Wine Mono and that after using winetricks I shouldn't get that error?

Any comment is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
I've tried [Updating Wine to 6 version](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-wine-on-ubuntu-20-04/). So fay, it does try to open the Logitech software, but it freezes each and every time.

Comment: The issue with anything that has to do with logitech g hub is that it is not designed for linux.  The programs you mentioned, wine, etc. are designed to bridge the gap, but as you now see, they don't function with every device/program.  Logitech needs to create a linux compatible package apparently for this particular device to work.  Otherwise you can search around and see if there are any Linux distros that may actually work with this device.  It may be easier to find a headset that's made for linux.

Answer (score 1):

The error you see with Wine is not actually related to Logitech G Hub. The developers of the package [changed the PPA](https://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-devel/2017-March/117104.html) used to distribute wine. So, if you installed wine using `apt install wine` this will install an older version which does not work on Ubuntu 20.04.

To fix the error `002b:err:mscoree:CLRRuntimeInfo_GetRuntimeHost Wine Mono is not installed`  first run `sudo apt purge wine` to remove the old version. Then follow the steps here: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu to install wine.

You can then retry the G Hub installation.